# Django template image won't load

Tags: python, html, css, django

Image won't load. I see o broken image icon. I use the static tag. I also tried giving the absolute path and never worked.I used the alt tag but still i can only see the broken image icon. Is the tag correct what else should i try.The images is in static\images\logo.png

```
{% load static %} {# loads static tag #}

.
.

 <div id="header">
   {% block header %}
     <img src="{% static "images/logo.png" %} alt="alternative text"  />
   {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: go through this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: did you copy/paste?  your quotes look screwed up

Comment: @jpwagner  <img src="{% static "images/logo.jpg" %}" alt=alternative text" />  . No the code is correct but still won't show anything. Its odd that now the borken icon is a bit bigger maybe for 1 or 2 pxs.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
{% load static %} {# loads static tag #}
```

to this:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

Comment: @KonstantinosKorovesis what version of django?

Answer (score 0):

1. check you static path setting in setting.py file

   **STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   '/PATH/OF/YOUR/STATIC/DIRECTORY',
   )**
2. if your static directory name is "static" then your path should be '/path-before-static/static' and you static URL should be.

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
3. your images should be within the static folder .../static/img/...jpg
4. In your template should be like this.

   {% load staticfiles %}
   {% static 'img/demo.jpg' %} or "{{ STATIC_URL }}img/demo.JPG"

**change setting.py file with This code**

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
]
```

Comment: 1.STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets','C:/Users/##$$^$^#/workspace/NoteDat/static'),

Comment: 2 AND 3 OK  4. {% load staticfiles %} {# loads static tag #} . Still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a production or development environment?

Can you access the /static/images/logo.png by typing it into the browser?

When in development, where debug is on I add this to the end of the urls.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

See here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#other-helpers

Comment: i don't the difference so i cant tell. But i know that i cant access the image by browsing http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/logo.png . I ll try that

Comment: DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG   . i used to code in the urls.py (the one that it is in project not the one in app forlder )But still nothing.

Comment: check the new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474969/django-template-image-wont-load-repost/20475710?noredirect=1#comment30600937_20475710

Comment: Have a look at the settings for STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in Django Two scoops: https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/blob/develop/project_name/project_name/settings/base.py

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what is that: normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')),

Comment: SITE_ROOT is set at the top of the configuration file, trace it back. First DJANGO_ROOT is set, then SITE_ROOT, then the STATIC_ROOT is set relative to SITE_ROOT.

Comment: This way you don't have to hardcode any absolute urls to your django project.

Comment: i ll check that tomorrow cause its late and that needs time. Thanx anyway i ll let you know how it goes

Answer (score -1):

```
{% load static %} {# loads static tag #}

 <div id="header">
   {% block header %}
     <img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="alternative text" />
     #check your quotes inside image tag.
   {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: Please add explanation