# Django jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am not able to run jQuery operations.I also tried other functions but nothing. I guess the problem is in handling static files as always.

notes.html:

```
    <div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/init.js" ></script>
    <h2><p id="title" > <a href="/notes/get/{{ note.id }}/" >{{ note.title }}</a></p></h2>
    <p id="body" > {{ note.body|lower|truncatewords:"10"}}</p> 
    </div>
```

init.js

```
$('#body').click(function(){

   $('#body').hide();

});
```

Comment: have you enclosed the `click` in `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: Are you even loading the jQuery from the Django server?

Comment: Is it possible your `static/js/jquery.js` url should be `/static/js/jquery.js` instead (note the leading slash)?

Comment: @Jason What i need to do ? . I am running Django from Eclipse. Explain plz

Comment: I would suggest rewriting your question to include what you're trying to do, how you're doing it, what you've tried so far and any error messages that show up in both Eclipse and browser consoles.

Comment: @jason i have no errors i am just checking if jquery works so i can do others things. This a the first thing i tried . Its so simply and its not working. From my little experience with Django templates i think that the problem is with statics files. It does load to the .js files.

Comment: NEW POST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706615/django-jquery-items-dont-work?noredirect=1#comment31015597_20706615

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few things to try:

1. Go into your settings.py file in the Django project.  Check that your `STATIC_URL` prefix is set to `/static/` and that `STATIC_ROOT = ''`
2. Verify that the path on your machine exists for `/static/js/jquery.js`
3. Open up Firebug or Chrome Inspector and verify that jQuery is loading.  In Firebug, this is under the Net tab, and you should see a GET request with jquery.js.  If you can see that, then enter `$.` in the Firebug console, which brings up a list of jQuery functions.

Comment: 1 ok , 2 ok ,  3 in Firebug console entered $ and got this:
>>> $
function() <------(its green but nothing in it).So i guess no jqueries

Comment: If you got `function()`, that means jQuery is loaded.  If it weren't, you would get a ReferenceError notice.  so the issue is not with Django, but your javascript code

Comment: Also tried that : $('#body').click(function() .Nothing . the problem is with static files or assets and settings or something. I never get those. What i need assets for? BTW i collected static already. I had a similar problem with just loading a img from static files using static tag. that took me i whole day too make it work.

Comment: Really ? every thing is in my question ,can you see anything wrong?

Comment: I would enclose everyting within a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... }` wrapper.  That ensures that the javascript doesn't execute until everything has loaded.

Comment: :( I understand what this does . Hell . nothing . so frustrating

Comment: i enter $ in the console in a url that doesn't have any JavaScript behind it and i got function() again ... Are you sure it loads the Jquery ?

Comment: Click the `function()` that shows up after you enter $.  It should load the jquery code in the firebug window.

Comment: $ function() <------(its green but nothing in it). I told you nothing was in it.  i also tried : <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}" ></script>. Still when i click nothing hides. It does load in .js files.

Comment: yes.  click on it if you can.  In firebug, that loads the source file at the function.  So if you're loading jquery, the jquery source code will show.  That means your issue is somewhere else

Comment: You dont say ... I know that. any ideas?

Comment: put a `console.log("body clicked")` logging statement inside the click handler?

Comment: Konstantinos Korovesis: Reading this thread I see Stack Overflow has a hard time helping you. The same is true with your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426612/django-template-image-want-load <- Did you resolve this? Than you should add an answer and accept it. If not, than get static files right before trying anything else. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files

Comment: @allcaps Thank you fro your interest . Yes people helped me with the last problem.I am just waiting for this to happen now. I have read all the documentations about static files.Its simple . But still not working.

Comment: @Jason i did it . Nothing. What's the point? statics files don't work.

Comment: @Jason change of plans. In Chrome inspector found that the static file are working.

Comment: NEW POST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706615/django-jquery-items-dont-work?noredirect=1#comment31015597_20706615

Answer (score -1):

"static/js/jquery.js" change to "/static/js/jquery.js" , i think your url is False

Comment: I wouldn't expect the static folder to be in the root directory, which is what you are implying...

Comment: @SamHuckaby . I also tried the absolute path <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\%#%@%\workspace\MyProject\static\js\jquery.js" ></script>. But nothing