# Django JQuery items dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am just checking if JQuery is working correctly in my Django project The one here is an exmple .When i put an event for an item it doesn't work.See my code and it ll be clear.It seems that the problem occurs when i call an item, like here "#text"

(1) test.js    WORKING:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Ready");
});
```

(2) test.js    NOT WORKING :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked");
    }); 
});
```

homepage.html:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/test.js" %}" ></script>
    <p id="text"> Click to hide </p>     
</div>
```

in test2.js in line 2 i also tried: `$('#text')` and  `$("text")` and  `$('text')` ...

Comment: `$("#text")click(function(){` You're missing a dot `.`. If this was a typo, make sure that `#text` is loaded. And why are you embedding script in `div` tags ?. Plus, Are you getting any error ? try firebug to find out.

Comment: @Mohammad Yaseen The . dot is originally there so that not the problem.I use Chrome Inspector and the .js files are loaded. That is why (1)test.ls works . i am using <div> tag in the example cause that's how i have it in my real project.No errors .

Comment: Are you sure that problem can't be in your rendering code ? I mean `render_to_resonse` ?

Comment: No the template is working perfectly

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612578/how-to-serve-static-files-in-django-development) might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django jquery wont work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687322/django-jquery-wont-work)

Comment: @allcaps What is your problem?

Comment: First off, why are you loading the scripts inside a `<div>` tag?  Why not put it in the `<head>` section?  Seems like it would make maintenance more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it is a result of delayed event binding, try using jQuery's event delegation via the `on()` function.  This would transform your existing

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#text").click(function(){
    alert("Text Clicked");
  });

});
```

into

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#text").on("click", function() {
    alert("Text Clicked");
  });

});
```

In the meantime, I would suggest that you modify the template to have the `<script>` tags within the `<head>` tags a la

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <title>APP TITLE</title>
    <link href = "/path/to/css" rel = "stylesheet" >
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static "js/jquery.js" %}"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <p id = "text">Click To Hide</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you . During x-mas i hound the solution and then i saw the answer.I don't know why this works better. My only problem for now is that the really thing i want to do is hide/show on mouseover and although the $('object') is in a for loop the jquery only works for the first print. I know its confusing. I might a make a question for it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#text").on('click',function(){
      alert("Clicked");
   }); 
});
```